# Conditional join not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two entities: `products` and `categories`. Products can be in multiple categories but is the vast majority they will be in one category (>99%).

I have a query that is supposed to return all products in a category. I have one column in the product table that indicates that the product is in more than one category (`CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities`). If so, only the `CwObject_MainCwEntity_Guid` is needed. Otherwise I need to do a join to a table that links Products (`CwObjects`) to Categories (`CwEntities`).

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT o.* FROM dbo.CwObject o WHERE CwObject_CwSiteCluster_Guid = '0f178176-9720-41c7-9528-99fdf30005e8' 
AND ((CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities = 0 AND CwObject_MainCwEntity_Guid = '4E614BA0-50E8-4CA1-9A42-D59DBDB6794D') 
OR (CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities = 1 AND
exists (select 1 from EntityObjectLink e where
e.EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwObject_Guid = o.CwObject_Guid 
AND e.EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwEntity_Guid = '4E614BA0-50E8-4CA1-9A42-D59DBDB6794D')
)) ORDER BY CwObject_NAME ASC
```

I have a testdatabase where there are no products in multiple categories so `CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities` is always `0`. I would have assumed that the `EntityObjectLink` would not be used at all because of this but the query still reads `63K records`.

The query plan is here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlCbN2sexrJ-hNJlfEvK07yamw75yw

Why is this happening?
How can I achieve this kind of `conditional join` otherwise?

Comment: have you considered using a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have considered and tried a left outer join as well but it has the same problem that all records are joined in stead of only the ones with CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities = 1

Comment: Gordon, the desired results would be that the query is a lot faster because it does not have to join all records to the EntityObjectLink but only the ones where CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities = 1. How would you propose sample data?

Comment: SO has a [guide to creating examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For SQL it helps to include 3 or 4 sample rows for each table.  Then using those sample rows show us the output you would expect.  This is your desired result.  If you can include a SQL statement that returns the sample rows (perhaps in temp tables or table vars) even better.  We can use this when answering your question.

Comment: How many records in your table match "CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities = 0 AND CwObject_MainCwEntity_Guid = '4E614BA0-50E8-4CA1-9A42-D59DBDB6794D'"? Is this your PK? Is it Unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the optimiser will try to work out the best way to run your query, and it might determine that this is to trawl through tens of thousands of records that it doesn't need.

Usually this would indicate a problem with indexes, but you might not be able to change your indexing strategy, or you could be perfectly happy with they way every other query executes?

You could try splitting the query up, to make it more "obvious" that there is no point in bringing in records that will end up discarded?  This might not help, but something like this:

```
SELECT
    o.*
FROM
    dbo.CwObject o 
WHERE 
    CwObject_CwSiteCluster_Guid = '0f178176-9720-41c7-9528-99fdf30005e8' 
    AND CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities = 0 
    AND CwObject_MainCwEntity_Guid = '4E614BA0-50E8-4CA1-9A42-D59DBDB6794D'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.*
FROM
    dbo.CwObject o
    INNER JOIN EntityObjectLink e ON e.EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwObject_Guid = o.CwObject_Guid 
        AND e.EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwEntity_Guid = '4E614BA0-50E8-4CA1-9A42-D59DBDB6794D'
WHERE
    CwObject_HasMultipleCwEntities = 1
ORDER BY
    CwObject_NAME;
```

I'm making some assumptions about the way your tables hang together.  You might find it better to remove the DISTINCT from the second part of that UNION and JOIN to a list of unique items from your link table (in a CTE or sub query) instead of the actual table?